# How to use wget in php?

Tags: php, wget

I have this parameters to download a XML file:

```
wget --http-user=user --http-password=pass http://www.example.com/file.xml
```

How I have to use that in php to open this xml file?

Comment: @nl-x i think that the selected answer (@Jack) provides an URI with authentication that is not documented (and might be not operational?) : PHP documentation tells that you have to use `stream_context_create` when authentication is needed with `file_get_contents()`

Comment: @Adam It's definitely operational - [proof](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/ext/standard/http_fopen_wrapper.c#535); and I don't see that particular requirement in the documentation.

Comment: @nl-x For auth basic, it works, but not for auth-digest.

Comment: try  http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/126490-wget-xml-isssue.html

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If the aim is to just load the contents inside your application, you don't even need to use `wget`:

```
$xmlData = file_get_contents('http://user:pass@example.com/file.xml');
```

Note that this function will not work if [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) is disabled (it's enabled by default) inside either php.ini or the web server configuration (e.g. httpd.conf).

If your host explicitly disables it or if you're writing a library, it's advisable to either use [cURL](http://php.net/curl) or a library that abstracts the functionality, such as [Guzzle](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org).

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new Client([
  'base_url' => 'http://example.com',
  'defaults' => [
    'auth'    => ['user', 'pass'],
]]);

$xmlData = $client->get('/file.xml');
```

Comment: I think cURL is a better Option than file_get_contents. Because allow_url_fopen is always problem. From security point of view that may be '0' .

Comment: The better option is to have it abstracted, actually :)

Comment: In addition to this answer, please refer to this post if you are working with large files. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27492007/file-get-contents-large-file-upload

Answer (score 61):

**wget**

[`wget`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget) is a linux command, not a PHP command, so to run this you woud need to use [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), which is a PHP command for executing shell commands.

```
exec("wget --http-user=[user] --http-password=[pass] http://www.example.com/file.xml");
```

This can be useful if you are downloading a large file - and would like to monitor the progress, however when working with pages in which you are just interested in the content, there are simple functions for doing just that.

*The `exec` function is enabled by default, but may be disabled in some situations. The configuration options for this reside in your `php.ini`, to enable, remove `exec` from the `disabled_functions` config string.*

**alternative**

Using [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) we can retrieve the contents of the specified URL/URI. When you just need to read the file into a variable, this would be the perfect function to use as a replacement for curl - follow the [URI syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax) when building your URL.

```
// standard url
$content = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/file.xml");

// or with basic auth
$content = file_get_contents("http://user:pass@www.example.com/file.xml");
```

*As noted by `Sean the Bean` - you may also need to change* [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php) *to `true` in your php.ini to allow the use of a URL in this method, however, this should be true by default.*

If you want to then store that file locally, there is a function [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) to write that into a file, combined with the previous, this could emulate a file download:

```
file_put_contents("local_file.xml", $content);
```

Comment: Excellent explanation, btw. I really appreciate this response. Prevented me from doing 2 more google searches.

Comment: Great explanation! Answers the question and provides an alternative that may be better, with examples of both. This should be the accepted answer. Also worth nothing again that `allow_url_fopen` must be enabled in your php.ini or else `file_get_contents` will not accept a URL.

Comment: Thank for the feedback, I have actually had this issue myself before! I updated the answer to include this fact, thanks! :D

Answer (score 11):

You can use `curl` in order to both fetch the data, and be identified (**for both "basic" and "digest" auth**), without requiring extended permissions (like exec or allow_url_fopen).

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/file.xml");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:pass");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Your result will then be stored in the `$result` variable.

Comment: Note that even though it's not affected by allow_url_fopen, it does require the cURL extension to be enabled.

Answer (score 2):

lots of methods available in php to read a file like exec, file_get_contents, curl and fopen but it depend on your requirement and file permission

Visit this [file_get_contents vs cUrl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970872/file-get-contents-vs-curl-which-is-more-relevant-and-secure)

Basically file_get_contents for for you

```
$data = file_get_contents($file_url);
```

Answer (score 2):

If using Curl in php...

```
function disguise_curl($url) 
{ 
  $curl = curl_init(); 

  // Setup headers - I used the same headers from Firefox version 2.0.0.6 
  // below was split up because php.net said the line was too long. :/ 
  $header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,"; 
  $header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5"; 
  $header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0"; 
  $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive"; 
  $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300"; 
  $header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"; 
  $header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5"; 
  $header[] = "Pragma: "; // browsers keep this blank. 

  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)'); 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header); 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.google.com'); 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate'); 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true); 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10); 

  $html = curl_exec($curl); // execute the curl command 
  curl_close($curl); // close the connection 

  return $html; // and finally, return $html 
} 

// uses the function and displays the text off the website 
$text = disguise_curl($url); 
echo $text; 
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

*This method is only one class and doesn't require importing other libraries or reusing code.*

Personally I use this script that I made a while ago. Located [here](http://api.kbcomp.co/http/) but for those who don't want to click on that link you can view it below. It lets the developer use the static method `HTTP::GET($url, $options)` to use the get method in curl while being able to pass through custom curl options. You can also use `HTTP::POST($url, $options)` but I hardly use that method.

```
/**
  *  echo HTTP::POST('http://accounts.kbcomp.co',
  *      array(
  *            'user_name'=>'demo@example.com',
  *            'user_password'=>'demo1234'
  *      )
  *  );
  *  OR
  *  echo HTTP::GET('http://api.austinkregel.com/colors/E64B3B/1');
  *                  
  */

class HTTP{
   public static function GET($url,Array $options=array()){
    $ch = curl_init();
    if(count($options>0)){
       curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       $json = curl_exec($ch);
       curl_close($ch);
       return $json;
     }
   }
   public static function POST($url, $postfields, $options = null){
       $ch = curl_init();
       $options = array(
          CURLOPT_URL=>$url,
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
          CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields,
          CURLOPT_HEADER => true
          //CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json')
          ); 
       if(count($options>0)){
           curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
       }
       $json = curl_exec($ch);
       curl_close($ch);
       return $json;
   }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to set `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` for something standard like POST; just set `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` and it will automatically set the right method ... also, you could use [`curl_setopt_array()`](http://php.net/curl_setopt_array) instead of loops.

Comment: That's very true, I made this when I first learned about curl and how it works. At the time, I didn't know about `curl_setopt_array()`, I'll update my answer just because I have been to lazy to update my actual script to use this method :3

Answer (score 1):

[Shellwrap](https://github.com/MrRio/shellwrap) is great tool for using the command-line in PHP!

Your example can be done quite easy and readable:

```php
use MrRio\ShellWrap as sh;

$xml = (string)sh::curl(['u' => 'user:pass'], 'http://example.com/file.xml');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function wget($address,$filename)
{
  file_put_contents($filename,file_get_contents($address));
}
?>
```

use:

```
<?php
wget(URL, FileName);
?>
```

Comment: Please add some explain how this answer help OP or others in fixing current issue instead of posting just code as answer.Thanks

Comment: The question requires the use of http authentication which this answer does not cover. Re-implementing `wget` in PHP should be avoided if `wget` already exists on the system.

Comment: Bad Practice, file_get_contents will get all the contents in memory prior of writing it with file_put_contents, thus could exhaust the server with large files

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to open a xml file using php. That's called to parse a xml file. The best reference is here.

http://php.net/manual/de/function.xml-parse.php

Answer (score 0):

> To run wget command in PHP you have to do following steps :
>
> 1) Allow apache server to use wget command by adding it in sudoers list.
>
> 2) Check "exec" function enabled or exist in your PHP config.
>
> 3) Run "exec" command as root user i.e. sudo user
>
> Below code sample as per ubuntu machine

```
#Add apache in sudoers list to use wget command
~$ sudo nano /etc/sudoers
#add below line in the sudoers file
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/wget


##Now in PHP file run wget command as 
exec("/usr/bin/sudo wget -P PATH_WHERE_WANT_TO_PLACE_FILE URL_OF_FILE");
```