# Is there an equivalent of the $.get() method in PHP?

Tags: php, get

I am trying to rerwite an application into php, which previously uses the $.get call in javascript, is there a way to call this in php so that i can use the response array 'answers'?

```
$.get('crawl.php', { text: passURL }, function(answer) {

    images = answer.images;

}, "json");
```

the only thing i found was the http_get method which doesnt seem to be responding with anything

```
$response = http_get('crawl.php', array( text=> $passURL), $answer);
$images = $answer['images'];
```

Am i just calling that method wrong or is there an alternative i should be using in php?

Comment: [Relevent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745587/how-to-use-wget-in-php/14745611#14745611)

Comment: @MattClark That question is a wonderful example of XY problem ... in fact, the accepted answer there makes a lot more sense in the context of PHP imho :)

Answer (score 2):

Try looking into [`curl`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or [`file_get_contents()`](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents).

You'll then want to use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) (or similar) to parse the resulting DOM or, if the result is `JSON` use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) on the resulting string.

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't work asynchronously like JavaScript does, so you would get this (assuming a JSON response):

```
$answer = json_decode(
    file_get_contents('http://host/path/crawl.php?' . http_build_query([
        'text' => $passUrl
    ])), 
    true
);
```

Alternatively, use [cURL](http://php.net/curl).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, PHP offers many ways to download data from a URL.

In fact if it has `allow_url_fopen` enabled in the config file, you can use pretty much any function that open files to load data from URLs aswell.

But to have a better control of headers, use POST etc. use [cURL](https://www.php.net/curl).

You may want to use `json_decode()` to parse the returned data the same way you do in JavaScript with `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: Btw, you can use POST with `file_get_contents()` too. Have a look at [`stream_context_create()`](http://php.net/stream_context_create).