# file_get_contents large file upload

Tags: php

I am trying to upload a large file above 2gb with fsockopen. But below error appears for file_get_content, I can't store large file in memory. I need to send the data in chunks but couldn't figure out how I will perform this operation. Kindly anyone can guide me?

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 727826869 bytes) in

```
    $file_info =  finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME);  
    $mime_type = finfo_file($file_info, $file_loc); 
    $file = file_get_contents($file_loc);

    $fp = fsockopen($host, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
    if ($fp) {
        $out = "POST /upload/".basename($url)." HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        $out .= "Host: ".$host."\r\n";
        $out .= "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8\r\n";
        $out .= "Content-Type: ".$mime_type."\r\n";
        $out .= 'Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_loc) . "\r\n";
        $out .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".urlencode(basename($file_loc))."\"\r\n\r\n";

        fwrite($fp, $out);
        fwrite($fp, $file);
        $response = '';
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $response .= fgets($fp, 128);
        }
        fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Have you tried to increase RAM?

Comment: I have limited RAM so I can't store 2GB and above files in memory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`file_get_contents` return contents of whole file as a single string variable. In your case it means it will try to create 2 GB variable which exhausts allowed script memory.

Try using `fopen` and `fgets`. This will allow you to process the file in smaller chunks.

```
$file_info =  finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME);  
$mime_type = finfo_file($file_info, $file_loc); 
$fileHandle = fopen($file_loc);

$fp = fsockopen($host, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if ($fp) {
    $out = "POST /upload/".basename($url)." HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: ".$host."\r\n";
    $out .= "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8\r\n";
    $out .= "Content-Type: ".$mime_type."\r\n";
    $out .= 'Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_loc) . "\r\n";
    $out .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".urlencode(basename($file_loc))."\"\r\n\r\n";

    fwrite($fp, $out);
    while(!feof($fileHandle)){
        fwrite($fp, fgets($fileHandle, 1024));
    }
    fclose($fileHandle);
    
    $response = '';
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $response .= fgets($fp, 128);
    }
    fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Exactly that, Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

`file_get_contents()` is going to return the contents of the specified url/file and return that data into your variable. That means if you're downloading a 10gig file, you'll need a 10gig memory limit (plus overhead) in PHP.

That's a ludicrous amount of ram for a simple script. You should be using a streaming system to download that much data. E.g. use byte-serving to fetch the url in smaller chunks, or use curl to write it out directly to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the file in chunks using [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) and [fread](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php)

```
function readFileChunked($filename) {
    $chunksize = 512 ; // bytes per chunk
    $handle = fopen($filename, "rb");

    if ($handle === false)
        return false;        

    while (!feof($handle)) {
        print fread($handle, $chunksize);            
        ob_flush();
        flush();
    }

    return  fclose($handle);
}
```