# Laravel - see HTML5 video from storage

Tags: php, html, laravel, video

I'm trying to display a video with HTML5 but the videos are in the storage folder because the user needs to be logged to watch it. 
The video is working fine, the problem is I can't skip forward and if you want to see the last minute, you need to see the whole video. If I upload the video to the public folder, this is working properly but I can't do it.
I'm using Laravel 5.2 if that helps.

Any suggestion?

HTML

```
<video width="100%" height="auto" controls>
    <source src="{{ route('get-video', ['filename' => 'video1.webm']) }}" type="video/webm">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Route

```
Route::get('storage/{filename}', function ($filename)
    {
        $path = storage_path('app/videos/' . $filename);

        return \Response::make(file_get_contents($path), 200, [
            'Content-Type' => 'video/webm',
            'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="'.$filename.'"'
        ]);

    })->name('get-video');
```

Thanks.

Comment: what library are you using for video ?

Comment: I'm not using any library. Just normal HTML5

Comment: @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27492007/file-get-contents-large-file-upload

Loading large files with `file_get_contents` can cause you memory overlap. Why don't you try to have a streaming-based service?

Comment: Thanks. I've never used it and I don't know how it works. It's the first time which I work with videos. I'm using this https://gist.github.com/ranacseruet/9826293 but I can't insert the video in a section of the page

Comment: I've inserted the code in a iframe and it seems work properly now. Thanks