# Trouble with POSTing audio file to PHP from iOS

Tags: php, ios, swift, avaudiorecorder

I am recording audio (as .m4a) in my application. That works just fine. I can make that data and I send it to my PHP script and it gets uploaded. However, it's no longer a valid audio file - it cannot be played when I download from my public server. Here is code for when the recording is complete, the generation of the body with headers, and my PHP. I also supply the response from the server which shows some things I believe I need to fix but am unsure about.

```
func finishRecording(success: Bool)
{
    if success
    {
        if NSData(contentsOf: audioRecorder.url) != nil
        {
            let destUrl = URL(string: destinationURL)
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: destUrl!)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            let param = ["firstName": "Eric", "lastName": "Dolecki", "userId": "5"]
            let boundary = "Boundary-\(NSUUID().uuidString)"
            request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

            do {
                let f = try FileHandle(forReadingFrom: audioRecorder.url)
                let data = f.readDataToEndOfFile()
                print(data) // i.e. 66505 bytes
                f.closeFile()

                // Lets send the file to the PHP script to save it.
                request.httpBody = createBodyWithParameters(parameters: param, filePathKey: "file", audioDataKey: data as NSData, boundary: boundary) as Data
                let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest)
                {
                    data, response, error in
                    if error != nil {
                        print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                        return
                    }

                    print("Response = \(String(describing: response))")
                    let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
                    print("Response data = \(responseString!)")
                }
                task.resume()
            } catch {
               ...
```

Here is the body creation function:

```
func createBodyWithParameters(parameters: [String: String]?, filePathKey: String?,
                              audioDataKey: NSData, boundary: String) -> NSData {
    let body = NSMutableData();
    if parameters != nil {
        for (key, value) in parameters! {
            body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n")
            body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
            body.appendString(string: "\(value)\r\n")
        }
    }
    let filename = "recording.m4a"
    let mimetype = "audio/m4a"
    body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n")
    body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(filePathKey!)\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
    body.appendString(string: "Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
    body.append(audioDataKey as Data)
    body.appendString(string: "\r\n")
    body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)--\r\n")
    return body
    }
}

extension NSMutableData {
    func appendString(string: String) {
        let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)
        append(data!)
    }
}
```

Here is the PHP:

```
<?php
$firstName = $_POST["firstName"];
$lastName = $_POST["lastName"];
$userId = $_POST["userId"];

$target_dir = "assets";
$target_dir = $target_dir . "/" . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir)) 
{
    echo "Status Okay: " . $firstName . ", " . $lastName . " : " . $userId . " " . $target_dir;

} else {
    echo "Error uploading";
}

?>
```

Server response:

```
Connection =     (
    "Keep-Alive"
);
"Content-Encoding" =     (
    gzip
);
"Content-Length" =     (
    50
);
"Content-Type" =     (
    "text/html"
);
Date =     (
    "Wed, 22 Aug 2018 13:29:04 GMT"
);
"Keep-Alive" =     (
    "timeout=5, max=100"
);
Server =     (
    "Apache/2.2.34"
);
Vary =     (
    "User-Agent,Accept-Encoding"
);
"X-Powered-By" =     (
    "PHP/5.3.29"
);
```

*The response I get has a content type of text/html and content-encoding of gzip. Those can't be good. I think that needs to be addressed - instead of multipart/form-data, what should it be (if that is the solution)? Will the PHP overwrite a file that already exists?*

Thanks for all your time and attention.

Comment: Are you able to play the file directly (i.e. download it, and play it with some media player)? Anyhoo, you need to set the proper headers in your PHP script.

Comment: I cannot play the downloaded file. What do the headers need to be?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49833586/2550501). You’ll have to change the content type to suit your file type though.. You could google the proper MIME-type.

Comment: @gnCupo I don't think my upload of the file is correct. I think my swift code needs revision. I am downloading the uploaded file via ftp and it cannot be played. I just want to ensure the upload via the PHP produces a valid audio file.

Comment: I solved this long ago. It had to do with the audio parameters which were wrong. So the file being sent after recording was corrupt and thus could not be played.